# Running a task in background on jsf form submit

Tags: asynchronous, jsf, ejb

In my JSF application i have a process that takes to long to complete and i don't want that the user keeps waiting till its finish. I'm trying to implement some kind of 'fire and forget task' to run in background.

I'm doing it using an `@Asynchronous` method. This is the right approach?

My controller:

```
@ViewScoped
@Named
public class Controller implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6252722069169270081L;

    @Inject
    private Record record;

    @Inject
    private Service service;

    public void save() {
        this.record.generateHash();
        
        boolean alreadyExists = this.service.existsBy(this.record.getHash());
        
        if (alreadyExists)
            Messages.add(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Error", "This record already exists"));
        else  {
            this.service.save(this.record);
            
            this.clearFields();
        }
    }
}
```

My service:

```
@Stateless
public class Service extends AbstractService<Record> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6327726420832825798L;

    @Inject
    private BeanManager beanManager;

    @Override
    public void save(Record record) {
        super.save(record);
        
        this.preProcess(record);
    }

    @Asynchronous
    private void preProcess(Cd cd) {
        // Long task running here ...

        this.beanManager.fireEvent(cd);
    }
}
```

But even with this approach the user keeps stuck at the page till the `preProcess` method finishes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that annotations that modify the behavior of EJBs (and CDI beans) are only applied when called by the "proxy" object that gets injected to appropriate injection points, like fields annotated with `@EJB` or `@Inject`.

This is because of how the containers implement the functionality that modifies the behavior. The object that the container injects to clients of EJBs (and normal-scoped CDI beans) is actually a *proxy* that knows how to call the correct instance of the target bean (e.g. the correct instance of e `@RequestScoped` bean). The proxy also implements the extra behaviors, like `@Transactional` or `@Asynchronous`. Calling the method through `this` bypasses the proxy functionalities! For this reason placing these annotations on non-public methods is effectively a NO-OP!

A non-exclusive list of solutions:

- Move `preProcess()` to a different EJB, make it public and keep the `@Asynchronous` annotation
- Make `preProcess()` public and call it from the `Controller`
- If the computation is truly private to the `Service` and exposing it would break design, and ou don't mind doing a bit more manual work, you can always run async tasks from the container-provided `ManagedExecutorService`:

  ```
    @Resource
    private ManagedExecutorService managedExecutorService;
  ```

  Pay attention to the semantics of the thread that executes your code - more specifically to what context values are propagated and what not! Well, you have to pay attention to that for `@Asynchronous` methods too!

Comment: I changed the `preProcess()` to public and call it from the `Controller` and now it works! Thank you!